# Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Map.Entry', required: 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: java

I am working on a simple project for fun, but I am getting an odd error while writing the test method. In it is a loop, and I have made sure that it causes the problem. It gives me this compilation error

`Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Map.Entry', required: 'java.lang.Object'`

The code is written as below:

```
        for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()){
            entry.getKey();
            entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"  "+entry.getValue());
        }
```

The searchUtil was wirrten to search in the sql,I have tested it and maybe it has not error.

```
public Map Search(T t, String... condition){
        JdbcPool pool = JdbcPoolImpl.poolEnum.INSTANCE.getPoolInstance();
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("select * from "+t.getClass().getSimpleName());
        Map map = new HashMap();
        try {
            conn = pool.getConn();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!"".equals(condition[0])){
            try {
                if (condition.length > 0){
                    sql = sql.append(" where "+condition[0]+" =?");
                    Method method = t.getClass().getMethod("get"+condition[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+condition[0].substring(1));
                    Object object = method.invoke(t);
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
                    ps.setObject(1,object);
                    if (condition.length>1){
                        for (int i = 1; i < condition.length; i++) {
                            sql = sql.append(" and "+condition[i]+" =?");
                        }
                        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
                        ps.setObject(1,object);
                        for (int i = 1; i < condition.length; i++) {
                            method = t.getClass().getMethod("get"+condition[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+condition[i].substring(1));
                            object = method.invoke(t);
                            ps.setObject(i+1,object);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            Field[] fields = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            int count = fields.length;
            int id;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    id = rs.getInt(1);
                    Constructor constructor = t.getClass().getConstructor();
                    T t1 = (T)constructor.newInstance();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        Method method = t.getClass().getMethod("set" + resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1).substring(1), fields[i].getType());
                        method.invoke(t1, rs.getObject(i + 1));
                    }
                    map.put(id,t1);
                }
            }catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally {
            pool.release(conn);
            JdbcUtil.close(ps,rs);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

I have googled it many times but have no function.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use raw types, `Map` is a generic interface, you may define the type of keys and values

```
// at method return type
public <T> Map<Integer, Object> Search(T t, String... condition){

    // at definition
    Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

}
```

And when retrieving and using it

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = foo.Search();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: kind of side question but... why not use var in the test suite? is it so that nobody starts using Long instead of Integer in the future, and things like that?

Comment: I get it ! Thank u. Java generics couldn't be weirder than they already are..

Comment: @RicardoAranguren I don't code Java from some years, so I didn't take the new `var` vibe for Java, even if I do it in Javascript